# What's the difference between removing a variable using a minus sign and select those wanted variables?

Tags: r, dplyr

In package `dplyr`, what's the difference between removing a variable using a minus sign and select those wanted variables?

For example:
K1 has 6 variables and the first one is called "id"
I want to remove the first variable.
    
    `K2 <- select(K1, -"id")

and
    K2 <- select(K1, 2:6)`

So what's the difference between these two?

Thank you for answering

Comment: as far as output is concerned there is no difference in both of them. It's just another way of doing the same thing. BTW, you don't need quotes `select(K1, -id)` should also work.

Comment: Also, maybe you have created a new temporary variable in a `%>%` pipe and want to remove it before exiting. In this case it's easier to use the minus sign.

Comment: Syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1):

They're essentially two ways to do the same thing.  In the examples you give, the result is just the same.  But when supplying additional arguments to `select`, it makes a difference if the first argument uses a minus sign.  From the help:

> If the first expression is negative, select() will automatically start with all variables.

So, these examples all give the same result.

```
library(dplyr)

foo <- data.frame(X = c(1,2,3),
                  Y = c(4,5,6),
                  Z = c(7,8,9))

select(foo, -X)   # Retains columns Y and Z
select(foo, Y, Z) # Retains columns Y and Z
select(foo, -1)   # Retains columns Y and Z
select(foo, 2:3)  # Retains columns Y and Z
```

But these give different results:

```
select(foo, -X, Y) # Retains columns Y and Z
select(foo, Y, -X) # Retains column Y
```

Basically, `select(foo, -X, Y)` means "Start with all the columns of `foo` except for `X`, and then add `Y` to that." But adding `Y` has no effect, because it was already included in "all the columns except for `X`".  So the result is the same as `select(foo, -X)`.

Whereas, `select(foo, Y, -X)` means "Start with column `Y` from `foo`, and then remove column `X`."  But since you only started with column `Y`, removing `X` has no effect, since it was already excluded.  So the result is the same as `select(foo, Y)`.